# tags will not store in database in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

Tags will not store in database in Django

```
def addque(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        user = request.user
        if user.is_anonymous:
            return redirect('addquery')

        if user.is_active:
            question = request.POST['question']
            body = request.POST['body']
            tags = request.POST['tags']
            aquuid = request.user.aquuid
            addquery = Question(question=question, user_id=aquuid, que_body=body, tags=tags)
            addquery.save()

            return redirect('addquery')
    else:
        return render(request, 'question/ask.html')
```

After giving the input the data is stored in the tags field but, not saving in the database. I can manually insert data through the admin panel successfully but not as a non-staff user. I have installed taggit and placed it in the installed_apps in settings.py. What is the issue with the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use model form

In html use id of forms like this

**HTML**

```
<form action="{% url 'addquery' %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<div class="psrelative">
<input id="id_question" name="question" type="text" maxlength="300" tabindex="100" placeholder="e.g. Is there an R function for finding the index of an element in a vector?" class="s-input js-post-title-field" value="" data-min-length="15" data-max-length="150" autocomplete="off" required>
</div>
<textarea name="que_body" id="id_que_body" class="textarea-body"></textarea required>
<div class="psrelative">
<input id="id_tags" name="tags" type="text" maxlength="300" tabindex="100"
placeholder="e.g. (ruby-on-rails vba spring)" class="s-input js-post-title-field" value="" data-min-length="15" data-max-length="150" autocomplete="off" required>
</div>
<button class="review-question-btn" type="submit" tabindex="120"> Submit your question
</button>
</form>
```

**Forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Question

class Addqueform(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ['question','que_body','tags']
```

**Views.py**

```
from .forms import Addqueform

def addque(request):
    queform = Addqueform(request.POST)
    if request.method == "POST":
        user = request.user
        if user.is_anonymous:
            return redirect('addquery')

        if user.is_active:
            if queform.is_valid():
                aquuid = request.user.aquuid
                question = queform.cleaned_data['question']
                body = queform.cleaned_data['que_body']
                tags = queform.cleaned_data['tags']
                addquery = Question(question=question, user_id=aquuid, que_body=body)
                for tag in tags:
                    addquery.tags.add(tag)
                addquery.save()
                return redirect('addquery')
            else:
                queform = Addqueform()
                return render(request, 'question/ask.html', {'form': queform})
    else:
        return render(request, 'question/ask.html', {'form': queform})
```

I think It will Work

Comment: Thanks for this code it will work

Answer (score 1):

Tags are Many-to-Many objects and you can't add those to an object until the object has been saved. The [documentation](https://django-taggit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#TaggableManager.add) shows that you need to use `.add()` to add tags to a model instance. Your code should be:

```py
    addquery = Question(question=question, user_id=aquuid, que_body=body)
    addquery.save()
    addquery.tags.add(tags)
```

As an aside, you might be better served by a ModelForm which can handle the tags and all of this stuff that you're doing:

```py
    question = request.POST['question']
    body = request.POST['body']
    tags = request.POST['tags']
```

https://django-taggit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/forms.html

Comment: Yes i will try but tag will store only one tag with input django,html store in db same in django,html it will not seprate please help me by way Thanks for answer

Comment: You probably need to use the taggit form for it to split out the different tags, see the link I put in my answer

Comment: plus one for the hint to use (Model)Forms :)

Comment: Problem is solved when i use model forms.....